# Override webform module submit

Tags: 7, webforms

I want to save webform submissions in node table..

I want to use the solution from "[How to create a node out of a webform submission?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235051)".

How can I implement it? I used **hook_form_alter** but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question about "[How to create a node out of a webform submission?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235051)" that you linked to, is about D8, while yours is about D7 ...

In D7, for sure,, you can use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module for this. As an example, consider this rule (in Rules export format), which does what you're asking for:

```
{ "rules_create_a_node_from_webform_data" : {
    "LABEL" : "Create a node from webform data",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "webform_rules", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "webform_has_id" : {
          "form_id" : [ "form_id" ],
          "selected_webform" : { "value" : { "webform-client-form-191" : "webform-client-form-191" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "The webform submitted contains these fields:\r\n\u003C\/ul\u003E\r\n\u003Cli\u003Ethe field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_title-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_title-value-raw]\u0022.\u003C\/li\u003E\r\n\u003Cli\u003E the field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_text-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_text-value-raw]\u0022.\u003C\/li\u003E\r\n\u003Cli\u003E the field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_number-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_number-value-raw]\u0022.\u003C\/li\u003E\r\n\u003Cli\u003E the field labeled \u0022[data:demoform_option-title]\u0022 which has value \u0022[data:demoform_option-value-raw]\u0022.\u003C\/li\u003E\r\n\u003C\/ul\u003E" } },
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : "[data:demoform_text-value-raw]" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "var_demoform_text" : "Form variable text" } }
        }
      },
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : "[data:demoform_number-value-raw]" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "var_demoform_number_text" : "Form variable number text" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_convert" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "integer", "value" : [ "var-demoform-number-text" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "conversion_result" : { "var_demoformvar_number" : "Form variable number" } }
        }
      },
      { "variable_add" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : "[data:demoform_option-value-raw]" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "var_demoform_option" : " Form variable option" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "param_type" : "article",
            "param_title" : "[data:demoform_title-value-raw]",
            "param_author" : [ "user" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "article_created" : "Created article" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "article-created:body:value" ],
          "value" : [ "var-demoform-text" ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "article-created:field-free-format-nr" ],
          "value" : [ "var-demoformvar-number" ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "article-created:field-optionlist" ],
          "value" : [ "var-demoform-option" ]
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "article-created:comment" ], "value" : "0" } },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "article-created" ], "immediate" : "1" } },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "A new article got created, with nid=[article-created:nid] and url=[article-created:url]" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Anybody a bit familiar with Rules and [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), while know that it's often a struggle to get access to the data contained in a submitted Webform. Mostly because they are not available to select them when building Rules Actions.

However by introducing those `var-demoform-...` variables (as in the above rule), you can make the typical Rules magic happen. Refer to [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199825/39516) to "[How to create a node from a Webform using rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199821/how-to-create-a-node-from-a-webform-using-rules)" for more details about all this.

Comment: @A.Sana Thanks for your accept / +1 ..."*that's great too!*". Next question?

Comment: my webform contains many components like address, phone number.. I need to save this data in fields table.. How can I do that? Thank you

Comment: @A.Sana How is the question in your last comment different from your original question here? Maybe you should post a new question about that?

Comment: If I do not seperate any role, normally all users can fill the webform.. is not it? even **anonymous**? in my case the event created in rules only fires if the admin that fills the webform

Comment: In my admin/reports/dblog, I have this message "Unable to get variable article_created, it is not defined."

Comment: in "entity_create" I replaced "param_author" : [ "user" ] by "param_author" : [ "site:current-user" ] and it works fine.. Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Try hook_form_alter into your custom module file.

```
/*
* Implement hook_form_alter()
*/
function mymodule_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state,$form_id ){
  // this is for your developer information and shows you the
  // structure of the form array
  dpm($form);
  // this will give you the details for my_form_component
  $a_component = $form['submitted']['my_form_component'];
  dpm($a_component);

  // you'll want to limit your altering to specific forms
  if ($form_id == 'my_webform_client_form_id') {
    // edit component values like this:
    $form['submitted']['my_form_component']['#title'] = 'A spurious text title';
    $from['#submit'] = 'custom_form_submit';
  }
}
```

https://www.drupal.org/node/1558246

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That doesn't work for me! I used @Pierre.Vriens 's solution