# How to save webform submissions data in fields using rules module

Tags: 7, entities, rules, webforms

I used the answer in my last question [Override webform module submit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258402/override-webform-module-submit/#258404)
to create node after webform submissions.

My webform contains many components like phone, address, responsible and others.

How can I save this data in fields tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that my webform contains the components: phone, address, city ..

I created a new content type that contains these fields: phone, address, city ..

Then, for each field I added

```
{ "variable_add" : {
      "USING" : { "type" : "text", "value" : "[data:address-value-raw]" },
      "PROVIDE" : { "variable_added" : { "var_address" : "Address label" } }
    }
  },
```

Where **address** is my **MachineFieldName**

and

```
  { "data_set" : {
      "data" : [ "article-created:field-address" ],
      "value" : [ "var_address" ]
    }
  },
```

To check your data as **[ "article-created:field-address" ]**

1. go to **admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/manage/rules_create_a_node_from_webform_data**
2. go to add action and select **set a data value**
3. in the Data selector *: select **article-created:...(Created article)** Then you will see all your fields..

This [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199821/how-to-create-a-node-from-a-webform-using-rules#answer-199825) to [How to create a node from a Webform using rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199821/how-to-create-a-node-from-a-webform-using-rules) helped me..

I hope that can help someone..

Thank you