# How to add files using rules module?

Tags: 7, rules, webforms, files

This question follows [Override webform module submit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258402/override-webform-module-submit)

Based on this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258402/override-webform-module-submit#answer-258404), I used the [rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to create a node after [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) submissions.

My webform contains an `<input type="file" />`

for other `<input type="text" />` I used [this solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258538/how-to-save-webform-submissions-data-in-fields-using-rules-module#answer-258602) to [How to save webform submissions data in fields using rules module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258538/how-to-save-webform-submissions-data-in-fields-using-rules-module)

How can I add this file data in the field-image table?

Comment: About your last phrase: (1) please explain what you mean by "file data", is it only the PATH where the file is stored and (2) is "field-image" the machine name of your node in which you want to store  the path of that file?

Comment: Yes! field-image is the machine name of my node. And for the first => how can save data where <input type="file" />

Comment: OK, you answered (2) in my prior comment, but NOT (1). Can you try again?

Comment: Thanks @Pierre.Vriens, yes it's only the PATH where the file is stored

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part of what you're trying to do, seems to be related to correctly specifying the filename of the attached file (= the value to be stored in your `field-image` field). For this, have a look at what is suggested in [Comment # 25](https://www.drupal.org/node/1431572#comment-6919340) of the support issue (not bug ...) [#1431572](https://www.drupal.org/node/1431572) and which states that the correct way to do so is something like so:

```
[node:field-file-attachments:file:path]
```

#### Use Rules debugging

This question is pretty tough to answer with the limited info you provided (and without access to "your" site). Therefor, if needed, you might also consider some Rules debugging, by (temporary) enabling the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, so that you can (temporary) add a Rules Action like "Display a value" (in your case of the entire node/webform that's used to submit that attached file). For way more details about such debugging, refer to **Rules debugging**, as explained in the answer to "[How can I display the value of a variable inside a condition?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199080/rules-debug-how-can-i-display-the-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-condition/199134#199134)".

Comment: the problem is my rules does not allow the import of values of type other than **text**. I added a text field to my content type and using the **hook_node_presave** to synchronize the two fields.. @Pierre.Vriens, Thank you