# Custom code for after submitting a webform

Tags: 8, nodes, webforms

**I have found this question here to fit my exact needs since the rules modules is not ready yet**

[How to create a node out of a webform submission?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235051/how-to-create-a-node-out-of-a-webform-submission)

I am hardly a coder, can someone please explain where i should use place this code in my Drupal 8 website ?

**MY USE CASE:**

1) **Content type (xyz) with below fields:**

- field_xyz_id (default Title field)
- field_xyz_name *(Text Field)*
- field_xyz_telephone *(Telephone field)*
- field_xyz_category *(Taxonomy reference field)*
- field_xyz_company *(Group reference field)*
- field_xyz_user *(User reference field)*
- field_xyz_color *(Color field)*
- field_xyz_image *(multi value image field)*

2) **Webform (registerxyz) with below fields:**

- form_registerxyz_name *(Text Field)*
- form_registerxyz_telephone *(Telephone field)*
- form_registerxyz_category *(Taxonomy reference field)*
- form_registerxyz_company *(Group reference field)*
- form_registerxyz_user *(User reference field)*
- form_registerxyz_color *(Color field)*
- form_registerxyz_image *(multi value image field)*

When a registered user with role **manager** submit the webform **regisyer xyz**, a new node of type **xyz** will be created and the webform submission value to be transfered to the node's fields.

**Back in D7:**
I used to use the **webform rules** to accomplish the above but until today both rules and webform rules are not ready yet

Any help in where i can place the above code in my drupal 8 website ?

I am open to any other suggestions (if any) to **create a node out of webform submissions !**

**UPDATE # 1:**

I have create a custom module (**my_module_name**) and inside `\my_module_name\src\Plugin\WebformHandler\ExampleWebformHandler.php` i have placed the below code:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module_name\Plugin\WebformHandler;


use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

use Drupal\webform\WebformInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\webformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission;


/**
 * Create a new node entity from a webform submission.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "Create a node",
 *   label = @Translation("Create a node"),
 *   category = @Translation("Entity Creation"),
 *   description = @Translation("Creates a new node from Webform Submissions."),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */

class ExampleWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
 // Create node object from webform-submission.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {

  /** @var Node $node */   
   $node = Node::create([
    // node type
        'type' => 'article',
    // mandatory fields
        'title' => $webform_submission->getData('subject'),
    // optional fields
        'body' => $webform_submission->getData('message'),
    ]);
    $node->save();

  }
}
```

I also under the **settings** of the default built-in **contact webform**, i have added the above handler.

Now, after i create a new Webform submission, the below errors appear in **the recent log messages section**:

**FIRST ERROR:**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: webformSubmission in Drupal\my_module_name\Plugin\WebformHandler\ExampleWebformHandler->submitForm() (line 45 of S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\modules\Custom\my_module_name\src\Plugin\WebformHandler\ExampleWebformHandler.php) #0 S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\core\includes\bootstrap.inc(582): _drupal_error_handler_real(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'S:\\Setup Ideas ...', 45, Array) #1 S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\modules\Custom\my_module_name\src\Plugin\WebformHandler\ExampleWebformHandler.php(45): _drupal_error_handler(8, 'Undefined varia...', 'S:\\Setup Ideas ...', 45, Array) #2 S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\modules\Contrib\webform-8.x-5.x-dev\webform\src\Entity\Webform.php(2250): Drupal\my_module_name\Plugin\WebformHandler\ExampleWebformHandler->submitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission)) #3 S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\modules\Contrib\webform-8.x-5.x-dev\webform\src\WebformSubmissionForm.php(1441): Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform->invokeHandlers('submitForm', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission)) #4 [internal function]: Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm->submitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #5 S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter.php(111): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #6...
```

**SECOND ERROR:**

```
Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in Drupal\my_module_name\Plugin\WebformHandler\ExampleWebformHandler->submitForm() (line 45 of S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\modules\Custom\my_module_name\src\Plugin\WebformHandler\ExampleWebformHandler.php) #0 S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\modules\Contrib\webform-8.x-5.x-dev\webform\src\Entity\Webform.php(2250): Drupal\my_module_name\Plugin\WebformHandler\ExampleWebformHandler->submitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission)) #1 S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\modules\Contrib\webform-8.x-5.x-dev\webform\src\WebformSubmissionForm.php(1441): Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform->invokeHandlers('submitForm', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), Object(Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission)) #2 [internal function]: Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionForm->submitForm(Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState)) #3 S:\Setup Ideas Sites\drupal8\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter.php(111): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #4...
```

Any help please ? look like i have to define some variables to hold the webform submissions !??

**UPDATE #2**

After fixing the **S** in the above code, and trying again to submit the **contact** webform, two new errors are now displayed:

Error Nbr1:

[image: Error Nbr 1]

Error Nbr 2:

[image: Error Nbr 2]

Your help is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: It's `WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission` so you need to call it the same inside the function `$webform_submission->getData()`

Comment: @theuni I updated my code as you mentioned in your last comment but still got the same error !!! FYI, the error message pointing that the error is at line 45 in the php code which is the line starting with the 'title'

Comment: Again, it's `$webform_submission->getData()`. You wrote `$webform_Submission->getData()` with a uppercase S

Comment: @theuni excuse my ignorance about the sensitivity of the php language code, however, after fixing the "S" issue i got two new error now... can you please check them out in the UPDATE #2 secrion (if you have time)... thank you

Comment: There could be many possible errors. Does the webform you built have a field (key) called 'title' that you access with `$webform_submission->getData('title')`? Try to go step by step from creating the webform to accessing the submission data inside the `submitForm()` function etc. Also for debuggin use `kint($webform_submission)` inside your `submitForm()` function to see what keys are available in `$webform_submission` and what values they have.

Comment: @theuni this is driving me crazy but i cannot find any problem in the code. **'title' => $webform_submission->getData('subject'),** the **title** in the code here return to the title of the node article being created and the **subject** return to a field inside the webform with key=subject

Comment: As @jrockowitz the maintainer of the webform module suggested, i tried to call **WebformSubmission::getElementData('subject'),** and **$WebformSubmission::getElementData('subject'),** but still no success at all.

Comment: See the slight modification in my answer's code. Try using `$values = $webform_submission->getData();` to get the data and then use `'field_xyz_name' => $values['name'],` to access them. Also, before you save the `$node` make sure to validate it's working - see my code modification

Answer (score 1):

As that link suggests, you can solve this problem by creating your own custom (webform submission) handler. So create a custom module (the easiest way is probably to use the [drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com) and run `drupal generate:module` in a terminal from your website's root folder). Besides all the necessary files for your module (like *.info.yml etc.) create a file named `your-module-name/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/CustomWebformHandler.php`. This is where your put all your logic of reading the webform submitted fields and saving them as a node.

As an additional help see this [link](https://gist.github.com/mharmuth/0ab021d5b65e4cab7c6efec951fc59e9) for an example of how to create a user after a webform submission (the function createUser() is where the node-creation logic is in this example).

**Update** To create your content type just write your logic similar to this code-draft and read more about custom webformhandlers.

```
class CustomWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {
  ...
  // Create node object from webform-submission.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {
    // Get an array of the values from the submission.
    $values = $webform_submission->getData();


    // Before you actually save the node, make sure you get what you
    // want. So at first comment the line further down with 
    // $node->save(), run the debug code, check the output and then
    // uncomment the $node->save() and delete the debug foreach loop.
    // You can use whatever debug method you prefer, this is just a
    // simple one-time example.
     foreach($values as $key=>$value) {
       drupal_set_message($key . ' -> ' . $value);
     }

    // This is the node creating/saving part.
    $node = Node::create([
      'type'        => 'type-of-your-content',
      'field_xyz_name' => $values['name'],
      'field_xyz_telephone' => $values['telephone'],
      ....
    ]);
    // Before you un-comment this line, make sure you get all the 
    // values you need from the webform data (in the foreach loop).
    //$node->save();
  }
}
```

Clear your cache.

Then in your webform's settings-general (UI) check "Disable saving of submissions".

Then under settings-email/handlers add your CustomWebformHandler as a new submission handler.

These are the basic steps that should help you move on.

Comment: thank you for your kind help, i will sure try the above explanation. I have one question for clarification: 1) the php code in that link above is what will go inside the customwebformhandler.php file right ?

Comment: Yes, modified accordingly based on your logic of course.

Comment: can you please check the update to my question !

Comment: Again, it's `$webform_submission->getData()`. You wrote `$webform_Submission->getData()` with a uppercase S

Comment: The answer is correct but you should use **WebformSubmissionInterface** in your function instead of **Webform_submissionInterface** because this is what being called in the update section of the question above.