# Unable to auto-create node from webform

Tags: 8, nodes, forms

I attempted to create a custom module that automatically creates a node upon submission. I used the second response in this post: [How to create a node out of a webform submission?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/235051/how-to-create-a-node-out-of-a-webform-submission?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Per the instructions, I added a php file to a new custom module created through Drupal console. It has an info.yml and .module files.

I took the code from the second comment and altered to suit my module, and add dependencies. (For some reason, the dependencies were incorrect.)

My PtcWebformHandler.php file contents:

```
<?php


namespace Drupal\ptc_node_from_form\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\webform\Annotation\WebformHandler;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;
use Drupal\webform\WebformSubmissionInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandler\EmailWebformHandler;



/**
 * Create a new Article node from a webform submission.
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "add_new_company",
 *   label = @Translation("Create a node on submit"),
 *   category = @Translation("Content"),
 *   description = @Translation("Creates a new Article node from Webform Submissions."),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 *   submission = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::SUBMISSION_REQUIRED,
 * )
 */

class PtcWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission)
  {
    // Get an array of form field values.
    $submission_array = $webform_submission->getData();

    // Prepare variables for use in the node.
    $title = $submission_array['subject'];

    // Create the node.
    $node = Node::create([
      'type' => 'company',
      'status' => FALSE,
      'title' => $title
    ]);

    $node->save();
  }
}
```

Before enabling the module, I added the email handler (the other post doesn't specifically say to, but it says a handler is required. And the code references an email array.)

After enabling the module, I submited a form, and checked for the node. And... no node.

I'm still getting used to Drupal 8 module development. I tried my hand at creating a service. But I doubt it is necessary (if I understand services). In any regard, it still doesn't create a new node upon form.  submission.

I tried to use xdebug to see what the data was being passed to the method inside the PtcWebformHandler class. It didn't hit anything.

What am I missing.

(It worked when I added the router from the first comment in the aforementioned post.)

Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/reroute_email

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a node type "company" that exists?
Is the machine name correct?
Does your $title have a correct value?

You might just be missing `->enforceIsNew()` but I'm not sure if that is required.

Try the below code and build further from there. (Edit the required values!!)

```
$newNode = Node::create([
  'type' => 'your_node_type_machine_name',
  'title' => 'the title of the new node',
]);

$newNode->enforceIsNew();
$newNode->save();
```

Also make sure you include

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
```

But looks like you already have that.